# Powerstate of Azure VM through powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

Fragment of my script looks like this:

```
# Collection of data
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "Environment" = $_.Tags.Environment
        "Application" = $_.Tags.Application
        "Decommission Date" = $_.Tags.Decomission
        "OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        "Data Disks Total Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Measure -Sum).Sum
        "Data Disks Amount" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Measure ).Count
        "Powerstate" = $_.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus
    }
}

$vmOutput | sort "Environment", "VM Type", "VM Profile", "Application" | export-csv VMReport.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

I want to add a power state column to the report, but it's not included in *Get-AzureRMVM* properties. I must add *-status* at the end of command to show me this data, but as I've noticed, it only works when specific resource group name and vm name is included.

How can I change the script to include power state as the last column in report without throwing this script away and writing a new one from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The instance view is the instance level status of the virtual machine.
>   Specify the Status parameter to get only the instance view of a
>   virtual machine.

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-1.0.0#description). So you just need to change some commands like these:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -Status
```

**and**

```
"Powerstate" = $_.PowerState
```

Then everything will be OK. Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does work when I run it in Powershell window, but not when run from Azure Runbook. This is the error comment:

Get-AzureRmVM : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: ResourceGroupName Name.
At line:31 char:8
+ $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -status

Azure Runbook sucks.

Comment: The AzureRm.Compute module in the Runbook version is 5.9.0 when created and there may be a bug in it. I got the same error in that version. But you can update the module to version 5.9.1. Then everything is OK.

Comment: @lubierzca Do you solve the problem with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

nothing you can really do about that, your best bet is doing something like this:

```
$vms = $vms | foreach-object { $_ | Get-AzRmVm -status }
```

so iterate over the vms variable to get each individual vm status